# Global variable as a parameter in a function and not being modified in that function

Tags: python-3.x

So guys I have the following problem I need a global variable to be modified in a function so in the next cycle it can go further in the range I need to

```
def down(turtleN,posx,posy,up): #function that needs to modify the global variables
    move = random.randint(0,1)
    if move == 1: #goes down to the left
       posx += 1
       posy += 1
       turtleN.goto(listPos[up][posx][posy])

    else: #goes down to the right
       if posy == 0: #keep it in range of the list
           posx += 1
           posy = 0
           turtleN.goto(listPos[up][posx][posy])

        else:
           posx += 1
           posy -= 1
           turtleN.goto(listPos[up][posx][posy])
def movimiento(N):
    global posx1
    global posy1
    global peso1
    posx1 = 0
    posy1 = 0
    peso1 = 0

    for k in range(N):
        down(turtle1,posx1,posy1,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the variables to be global, why do you use them as arguments of your function? Remove them from your arguments and declare it rather as a global variable with the `global` statement (as you do in the other function).

Comment: The problem is that this is only one of 4 cases of the function down so I wast not planning on doing basically the same thing 4 times so I thought of something like this but I guess I will have to do it 4 times over or do you have any other option?